# Create custom legend control using L.ExtraMarkers.icon icons in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers, icon, leaflet-plugins

Is there any way I can add [Leaflet Extramarkers](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) to my legend? From what I googled, it seems I'll have to add an image of markers... however I was hoping I could use the ones I created.

```
var Icon = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                        icon: 'fa-graduation-cap',
                        markerColor: theIcon,
                        shape: 'circle',
                        prefix: 'fa'
});


function theIcon(ct){
    if (ct == "Public"){
        Icon.options.markerColor = "orange"
    }
    else if (ct == "Private"){
        Icon.options.markerColor = "cyan"
    }
    else{
        Icon.options.markerColor = "red"
    }
    return Icon
}


function style(feature, latlng){
    
    switch (feature.properties.Sector){
                case 'Public'  : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: theIcon("Public")}).addTo(map); 
                case 'Private' : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: theIcon("Private")}).addTo(map);
    }
}

var univ = new L.WFST(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs',
            typeNS: 'HEC',
            typeName: 'Unis',
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
            geometryField: 'the_geom',
            showExisting: true,
            maxFeatures: 500,
        },
    new L.Format.GeoJSON({
        pointToLayer: style,     
    })
);
```

Edit:

Code for the legend that I am trying to create is:

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = ['Public', 'Private', 'Selected'];

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML += 
            '<i style="background:' + theIcon(grades[i]) + '"></i> ' +  grades[i] +  '<br>';
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: What is "my legend"? Please edit your question with additional info about what are you trying to do.

Comment: It's also not clear how you expect `markerColor` option to work, since you specified `theIcon` function. It should be character string, specifying marker color, and this only if `svg` option is se to `true`.

Comment: My legend - I meant the legend that I am creating. It’s not a library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L.ExtraMarkers.icon` is an extension of standard Leaflet `L.icon`, which means actual icon HTML code is created only after marker is added to the map, and even then icon HTML code is accessible only through internal `._icon` property.

But icon HTML code can be created also independently of map markers with the `.createIcon()` method. To use the icon outside marker context, its CSS style has to be modified a bit, so in your case code could look something like this:

CSS

```
.legend-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
.legend-icon .leaflet-marker-icon {
  position: relative !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

JS

```
var markerColor = {
  "Public": "orange",
  "Private": "cyan",
  "Selected": "red"
};

function theIcon(ct){
  var icon = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
    icon: 'fa-graduation-cap',
    markerColor: markerColor[ct],
    shape: 'circle',
    prefix: 'fa'
  });
  return icon;
}

var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {     
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
  var grades = ['Public', 'Private', 'Selected'];
  div.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
     var icon = theIcon(grades[i]).createIcon();
     div.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-icon">' + icon.outerHTML + '</div><div class="legend-icon">' + grades[i] + '</div></br>';
  }
  return div;
};      
legend.addTo(map);
```

That's how it looks like then:

[image]